# Scripting: get number of root files in RAR archive

Tags: bash, grep, unrar

I'm trying to write a bash script that determines whether a RAR archive has more than one root file.

The unrar command provides the following type of output if I run it with the `v` option:

```
[...@... dir]$ unrar v my_archive.rar

UNRAR 4.20 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2012 Alexander Roshal

Archive my_archive.rar

Pathname/Comment
              Size   Packed Ratio  Date   Time     Attr      CRC   Meth Ver
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
file1.foo
           2208411  2037283  92% 08-08-08 08:08  .....A.   00000000 m3g 2.9
file2.bar
               103      103 100% 08-08-08 08:08  .....A.   00000000 m0g 2.9
baz/file3.qux
           9911403  9003011  90% 08-08-08 08:08  .....A.   00000000 m3g 2.9
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3         12119917 11040397  91%
```

and since RAR is proprietary I'm guessing this output is as close as I'll get.

If I can get just the file list part (the lines between `------`), and then perhaps filter out all even lines or lines beginning with multiple spaces, then I could do `num_root_files=$(list of files | cut -d'/' -f1 | uniq | wc -l)` and see whether `[ $num_root_files -gt 1 ]`.

How do I do this? Or is there a saner approach?

I have searched for and found ways to grep text between two words, but then I'd have to include those "words" in the command, and doing that with entire lines of dashes is just too ugly. I haven't been able to find any solutions for "grep text between lines beginning with".

What I need this for is to decide whether to create a new directory or not before extracting RAR archives.
The `unrar` program does provide the `x` option to extract with full path and `e` for extracting everything to the current path, but I don't see how that could be useful in this case.

---

**SOLUTION** using the accepted answer:

```
num_root_files=$(unrar v "$file" | sed -n '/^----/,/^----/{/^----/!p}' | grep -v '^  ' | cut -d'/' -f1 | uniq | wc -l)
```

which seems to be the same as the shorter:

```
num_root_files=$(unrar v "$file" | sed -n '/^----/,/^----/{/^----/!p}' | grep -v '^  ' | grep -c '^ *[^/]*$')
```

**OR** using `7z` as mentioned in a comment below:

```
num_root_files=$(7z l -slt "$file" | grep -c 'Path = [^/]*$')
# check if value is gt 2 rather than gt 1 - the archive itself is also listed
```

---

Oh no... I didn't have a man page for `unrar` so I looked one up online, which seems to have lacked some options that I just discovered with `unrar --help`. Here's the **real solution**:

```
unrar vb "$file" | grep -c '^[^/]*$'
```

Comment: `7z` can list the contents of some `rar` files with `l` switch and its output seems better structured.

Comment: D'oh, I already had a solution for `zip` files using that! The question is though, what does "some `rar` files" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I haven't been able to find any solutions for "grep text between lines
>   beginning with".

In order to get the lines *between* `----`, you can say:

```
unrar v my_archive.rar | sed -n '/^----/,/^----/{/^----/!p}'
```

Comment: Thanks! I see. That works for the first part. Would it be possible to add something that also removes the lines with filesize, timestamp et c?

Comment: @gaidal I assume that those are lines starting with a space.  If that is so, append `| grep -v "^ "` to the above command.

Comment: Yes, or with two spaces since there is one before the filenames too. I guess it's not possible or convenient to add it to the sed line then. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

"rar v arcname.rar" lists the total number of files in archive in the last output line. You can add -idn switch to remove file names from listing.